# knockout observablearray in 2 templates

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js

I have 2 observabeleArrays. One contains all the possible types which I can select and the other one contains all the selected ones. The first template shows all the possible types and the other all the selected ones. If I click on one of first template(all possibilities), it gets added to the list of selected ones and is displayed in the second template. If I click on a selected one in the second template it is removed from there. Also, in the first template I want to display a check on the objects that are selected. Most of the stuff works, except the check does not get updated if I remove an object via the second template. I've tried to reduce my code to the important parts, I hope it makes more sense like this and doesn't have any mistakes: 
Anyone an idea how to fix it, so my check shows correctly? It's depending on the Selected value of each object, which updates correctly, but the view doesn't change.

```
//main html
//...
            <div data-bind="component: {
                    name: 'selector-component',
                    params: {
                        selected: vm.selected,
                        types: vm.types,
                    }
                }">
            </div>
            <div data-bind="component: {
                    name: 'selected-component',
                    params: {
                        selected: vm.selected,
                    }
                }">
            </div>
//...
<script type="text/javascript">

    vm.selected = ko.observableArray([]);
    vm.types = ko.observableArray([]);

        ko.components.register('model-selected-component', {
            template: { element: document.getElementById('selector-component-template') },
            viewModel: SelectorComponentModel
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    vm.selected = ko.observableArray([]);

        ko.components.register('model-selected-component', {
            template: { element: document.getElementById('selected-component-template') },
            viewModel: SelectorComponentModel
        });
</script>           

//template1
<template id="selector-component-template">
                    <div class="panelContainer">
                        <!-- ko foreach: types -->
                                <a data-bind="attr: {title: Name}, click: $parents.select" class="thumbnail text-center" href="#">
                                    <span style="display:block;height:10px;width:10px;">
                                        <i data-bind="visible: Selected" class="fa fa-check" style="color:green"></i>
                                     <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/type.png")" />
                                   </span>
                                </a>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
</template>


//template2
<template id="selected-component-template">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Selected Properties</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel-body panel-body-nobottompadding">
                <div class="panelContainer">
                    <!-- ko foreach: selected -->
                        <a class="thumbnail text-center" data-bind="attr: {title: Name}, click: $parent.select">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/type.png")" />
                        </a>
                    <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

//selector.js
function SelectorComponentModel(params) {

    var self = this;
    self.selected = params.selected || ko.observableArray([]);
    self.types = params.types || ko.observableArray([]);

    self.select = function (types) {
        if (self.selected.indexOf(types) == -1)
            self.selected.push(types);
        else
            self.selected.remove(types);

        types.Selected = types.Selected == true ? false : true;
        //refresh
        var data = self.types();
        self.types([]);
        self.types(data);
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do i fix it, so my check shows correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to maintain two separate arrays. Just make one array for all items and `computed` array for selected items only.

```
self.items = ko.observableArray();

self.items.selected = ko.computed(() => {
    return self.items().filter(item => item.selected());
});
```

Take a look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/5mquej1f/).

**Update**

As you may see I use arrow functions alot. However they are part of ES6 standard supported by most modern browsers your experience may differ. For such unlucky users there is [more classic example](https://jsfiddle.net/5mquej1f/1/).

**Update 2**

Of course your `Selected` property must be *observable*. You can convert this property for each item before assigning to the model.

[Updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/5mquej1f/3/)

Comment: I believe that arrow functions are not yet commonly available across all browsers.

Comment: @Tomalak, of course. It's just the example. It's simple to rewrite arrow functions in normal form.

Comment: But why write it in a way that is unusable for the target audience in the first place?

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem with displaying the check. The selected value is updated correctly, but it doesn't refresh. Also, the first array is quite big and the second one is used for transferring data. It's supposed to be 2 different ones...

Comment: @lupus, what do you mean when "it doesn't refresh"? Also no matter how big is the first array because you always can use _computed_ array as different plain array.

Comment: this line shows a green check mark, if it is selected.
 <i data-bind="visible: Selected" class="fa fa-check" style="color:green"></i>
 If I change the value via the second template, the Selected value of each object in the array updates, but the check itself doesn't change.

Comment: It's because your `Selected` property is not _observable_. So there is no dependency between the DOM element and the property. You have to make `Selected` property observable for each `param.types` item before assigning this array to `self.types`.

Comment: @f_martinez, I get the array already in that form. Can I change it after assigning?

Comment: sorry, I didn't refresh before answering and didn't see the update. thanks a lot, that worked perfectly! and it is a minimum of changing code as well!

Comment: @lupus, look at [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/5mquej1f/3/). You can intercept passed array in your `SelectorComponentModel` constructor like I'm intercepting in my `VM`.

Comment: @lupus. Ok, glad to help.