# knockout checked binding doesn't update

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, checked

I have list of objects I can select. I made a select all checkbox to click which selects all. The selecting works, but it doesn't update the checkbox value itself. Also, deselecting doesn't work, because the value is never true.

```
//html
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selecAllBT, click: selectAll" /> Select all
//other stuff

//JS
    self.selecAllBT = ko.observable(false);

    self.selectAllBodyTypes = function (self) {
     for (i = 0; i < self.items().length; i++) {
        if (self.selecAllBT() != self.items()[i].selected()){
            self.toggleSelected(self.items()[i]);
        }
    }
    self.selecAllBT(!self.selecAllBT);

    return true;

   }
```

I put it in a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5mquej1f/21/
(I actually reused a JSFiddle from another issue of me, in case somebody recognizes it: [knockout observablearray in 2 templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161828/knockout-observablearray-in-2-templates))

Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?
thx

Answer (score 3):

You're implementing the same functionality twice:

The checkbox has toggle behaviour by default, implemented by your browser. Knockout plugs in to this functionality using the `checked` binding. You pass it an observable, and the value is stored:

```js
var VM = function() {
  this.selectAllBT = ko.observable(false);
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectAllBT" />toggle
</label>
<div>
  Value: <span data-bind="text: selectAllBT"></span>
</div>
```

### The problem

Now, you've also included a `click` binding. This binding listens to a `click` on any element. In your click listener, you toggle the value by:

```
self.selecAllBT(!self.selecAllBT);
```

Then, you `return true`, passing the event to the checkbox. The checkbox will change naturally, and bound value will toggle *again*, **changing it back to the old value**.

### Solution

A better way of implementing this, is removing the `click` listener and adding a `subscribe` to your checkbox value in the code behind:

```js
var VM = function() {
  this.selectAllBT = ko.observable(false);
  
  this.doSomethingElse = function(selectAllValue) {
    console.log("Do work for new selectAll state:", selectAllValue);
  }
  
  this.selectAllBT.subscribe(this.doSomethingElse, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectAllBT" />toggle
</label>
```