# Get checked attributes in recursive knockout

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js, click

I have a recursive dom in KnockoutJs:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tree-hierarchy', foreach: someArray }"></ul>
<script id="some-tree" type="text/html">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { id: id, name: name, value: value}, click: someFunc">
   </li>
</scrpt>
```

I want to get the checked element's attributes so I use click functionality to get the data in the fucntion:

```
someFunc(data: any, event: any) {
   //event.target gets me the attributes
}
```

I get the data I want in event.target, but immedialtly checked becomes unchecked.
If click functionality is not there, like this, checked remains:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { id: id, name: name, value: value}>
```

The check remains, but when 'click' functionality calling the function is present, it unchecks immediately.
I want it to remain. I dont want to use 'checked: boolValue', functionality of knockout, since it is dynamically created and if there are 10 values in array, there would be 10 checbox inputs, hence having one bool value makes no sense.

I want checkbox to remain checked, after the call to  function is completed.

Comment: You can define a Boolean property on each item inside the `someArray` collection which accounts for whether the check box is checked or not for that particular row. Then each row will have its own checked/not checked state...

Comment: You shouldn't use a `click` binding on a checkbox. Knockout has a `checked` binding. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267755/3297291)

Comment: Removed checkbox and added two spans with click functionality and got it to work.